# Conditions in implode function

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I am doing an implode on my array:

`$values = "('".implode("', '", $array)."')";`

It gives me results like this:

`('abc', '123', 'apple123', 'hello', '345')`

I need it to look like below, so the numbers will not be in quotation marks:

`('abc', 123, 'apple123', 'hello', 345)`

The problems is that the mysql database doesn't want to import the data properly. It sees the numbers as strings and gives them max possible int value so the imported values do not match what I have.

Is there any way to add some more instructions to implode so it would recognize what is number and what is not?

Comment: you have to iterate trough the array

Comment: Sounds like you should be using prepared statements, but you only show how you generate a string.  If this is building an INSERT statement, have a loop at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment by @GrafiCode, you can't do what you're asking for.

A quick workaround would be to take advantage of `json_encode`'s behavior that leaves integer values as unquoted (as expected):

```
$data = array('abc', 123, 'apple123', 'hello', 345);

$insert = trim(json_encode($data), '[]');

// Output is: "abc",123,"apple123","hello",345
// (You can add the round brackets yourself).
```

### However:

It seems you're building a query dynamically. If you were to do something like this:

```
$placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($data), '?'));
```

Then you can use parameterized queries / prepared statements, which are **much safer**:

```
$q = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO people VALUES ({$placeholders})");
$q->execute($data);
// This is also possible in MySQLi and other database APIs, not just PDO.
// The string would look like this: INSERT INTO people VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
// Every question mark is replaced by one value from the array 
// when the query is executed.
```

You send the (dynamic) data *after* building the query and don't need to concern yourself with quoting.

Prepared statements are also an excellent defense against SQL injections.